# Why couldn't the Children of the Forest give good powers to people to help defeat the White Walkers

Tags: game-of-thrones

We know the CotF have magical powers. They can even make humans special, giving them powers, such as the Night King being stabbed by dragonglass in a set of conditions that gave him different powers. Why can't the CotF do the same for someone else, but in a positive way, giving them a strong power such as conjuring fire, or a mild one even.

Comment: On a hunch, because they thought that's *what they were doing the first time*.  Turned out rather well no?  (or for a snarkier spin to this, because Martin wrote this story, not Rowling).

Comment: We know the CotF have magical powers, but we don't know the limits of their powers. This question makes little sense to me. Do you have any evidence that they could do any of the things you propose?

Comment: For starters, in the TV series they all appear to be dead. If you also want answers from the novel, you can [edit] your question to add the [asoiaf] tag.

Comment: Also adding to what @Radhil said, the reason is that "A Song of Ice and Fire" is *not* another corny, boring young adult (YA) book series, where the protagonists are cool teenagers with super powers that in the end save the world. In real life (and in ASoIaF), those kids would die horrible deaths...

Comment: @Loki - People have this impression. But is it true? Twelve viewpoint characters have died so far in ASoIaF, as shown [here](https://www.quora.com/In-ASOIAF-how-many-POV-characters-have-died-so-far).  Of those, only Ned Stark and Jon Snow could really be considered major characters. We’re not counting Catelyn Stark, for rather obvious reasons (being resurrected and all). Jon Snow’s dead in the books…but who really thinks he’ll stay that way?
 
And the teenagers with super-powers in ASoIaF (Bran, Arya, Daenerys) are all still alive…and may yet save the world.

Comment: Isn't it enough that they teamed up with the three eyed raven then helped give Bran superpowers and (probably) helped give the Starks a direwolf each via him (probably) warging the pregnant wolf through the wall to just the right spot then impailing itself on a stag just after giving birth as a symbolic warning to not go south with the Baratheon?

Comment: @tobiasvl The evidence we have that the CotF can do these things is in the show they created the White Walkers this way. And this is tagged as the show, not the book.

Comment: @IronSean There's no evidence in the show that they have powers to give someone else strong powers, like conjuring fire, in a positive way.